# Displaying a different view when user is logged in swift not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, swift3

I am developing an app in `Swift3`, and using `Parse`.

For my start screen, I have a `Sign In` page. However, I want it to automatically go to the `Home` screen if the user is `Logged In`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if PFUser.current() != nil {
        print((PFUser.current()?.username)!)
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowHomePage", sender: self)
    }
    else {
        print("No User Logged in")
    }
```

That's my code on the `SignIn` page. Im getting the print message showing me that a user is `Logged In`, however, it's not actually going to a different view.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does the identifier "ShowHomePage" exactly match the identifier set in the storyboard?

Comment: yeah, exactly the same

Comment: I tried without using parse its working fine

Comment: So you are logged in but is not perfuming the segue? Have you tried to put `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowHomePage", sender: self)` inside `DispatchQueue.main.async { }` if you are using swift3

Comment: That looks fairly sound to me on the segue front. Are you absolutely sure that the username is coming back? I assume that you aren't directly calling `viewDidLoad` from elsewhere in your controller.

Comment: `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowHomePage", sender: self) inside DispatchQueue.main.async { }` That worked, thank you :-)